# Why is time.clock giving a greater elapsed time than time.time?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, time, multiprocessing

I timed a section of python code on Ubuntu using `time.clock` and `time.time`:

```
clock elapsed time: 8.770 s
time  elapsed time: 1.869 s
```

I understand that time.time uses system time and time.clock uses the processor clock. It makes sense to me when time.time gives a larger elapsed time than time.clock: the processor was just not active the entire time (e.g. time a call to `time.sleep`).

But why/when would the processor clock give an elapsed time so much *greater* than the system time does?

---

*addendum*

I did a rough test computing the same function with a standard map, with a process pool map, and a thread pool map. Understandably, the process pool is faster and the thread pool is slower. More interestingly: the clock timing is *less* than the time timing with the processor pool but *greater* in the thread pool.

Again, I understand why the clock timing is less with the processor pool: presumably the master process doesn't do much and just waits for the pool processes to complete. But why is the clock timing more with the thread pool? Any insights?

Results:

```
map
  time  1738.8
  clock 1739.6
mp pool
  time   580.1
  clock   15.9
thread pool
  time  3455.3
  clock 5378.9
```

Code:

```
from time import clock, sleep, time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random

def f(i):
    x = [random.random() for j in range(100000)]
    return x[i]

def t(fn):
    t0, c0 = time(), clock()
    for i in range(10): fn(f,range(16))
    print '  time ', round(1000*(time()-t0),1)
    print '  clock', round(1000*(clock()-c0),1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'map'
    t(map)

    pool = Pool(8)
    print 'mp pool'
    t(pool.map)

    pool = ThreadPool(8)
    print 'thread pool'
    t(pool.map)
```

Comment: Something parallel? Are you running on 8 cores?

Comment: Yes, that's my suspicion as well. So does clock give an elapsed clock time for all of the processors?

Comment: Could be OS-specific, but I've seen similar issues with many timing tools/libs

Comment: I'm on a Linux mint.

Comment: Are there other processes running, or is your process is bound? What's been happening here is the processor is active and is not, or cannot execute instructions for your process. It was my understanding that time cannot be greater than clock.

Comment: See http://pymotw.com/2/time/ for a good explanation of the difference between wall clock and processor clock time.

Comment: @Dunes I should note that this isn't two separate runs, but two timings of the exact same run. It's consistent across multiple runs (always about 8.8 seconds for clock and about 1.9 for time). Lastly, I sat in my chair for about 2s, so the clock is truly longer than the real run time.

Comment: @LukasGraf Thanks, but that just explains what I already know (and summarized above). It doesn't explain how the processor clock time could be greater than the wall time. In addition, it suggests that clock should be used for benchmarking, which I understand to be incorrect (timeit, for example, uses time not clock on Linux).

Comment: @LukasGraf: actually the motw explanation is incorrect. Read the current version of [`time.clock()` docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/time.html#time.clock) — the function behaviour is *platform-dependent* and it is deprecated since Python 3.3. It should *not* be used for performance measurements even on Python 2 on Linux.  Use `timeit.default_timer` that gives you the best timer for performance measurements on your system regardless of Python version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CPU time can exceed wall time if you execute on multiple CPUs. I've not specifically seen this in Python, but I've definitely seen this when using the `clock` function with multiple threads from C, and presumably the Python code is just directly calling this C function.

Regarding "why": you're thinking about it the wrong way. What's important is *how many* cores are running your program. If one core runs for one second over the course of two seconds of wall time that makes sense to you, but what if four cores each run for one second over that same time interval. Then you have 4 seconds of CPU time in 2 seconds of wall time. The kernel accounts for CPU time measuring all cores. If multiple cores run during the same second then you spent multiple CPU seconds during that second. That's the cost measurement that matters to the scheduler, and presumably that's the metric which `clock` is built upon. This may not be the metric you care about, but that's how it works.

Comment: Empirically, that seems to be the case. Why?

Comment: The documentation for [`std::clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) simply states this as a fact.

Comment: I'm trying to find out why. What is the processor clock measuring? It seems to measure the amount of time the processor is active, but that can't be totally accurate because the processor can't be active for more time than has actually passed (or can it, because of the way multi threading works at the hardware level?) The answer you've provided corroborates my experience and points out that it is documented (ie not a bug). But it doesn't explain why.

Comment: @jmilloy: On my system `time.clock()` calls [`clock(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) C function that is implemented using `clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID)` that [*"represent the amount of execution time of the process associated with the clock"*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) -- it doesn't count CPU-time of the child processes, it seems to count CPU-time ("execution time") for each thread that is why the clock time maybe larger than the wall time for multithreaded processes on multicore CPU.

Comment: @jfs can you post it as answer, it's very useful.

Comment: @max it is not an answer. My comment just provides some additional info (example) in the context of the current answer.