# How do I see the time it took to run my program in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, compiler-optimization

Is there a way to see how long a script took to execute/complete in VS Code?

I'm looking for a message like:

```
Program finished in 30ms
```

Comment: use a shell command to time the execution (Unix `time`), for python use the `timeit` module

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use 'time'

When your script starts:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

do something # here your actual code/routine

print("Process finished --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a simple decorator function to time your functions.

```
import time

def decoratortimer(decimal):
    def decoratorfunction(f):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            time1 = time.monotonic()
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            time2 = time.monotonic()
            print('{:s} function took {:.{}f} ms'.format(f.__name__, ((time2-time1)*1000.0), decimal ))
            return result
        return wrap
    return decoratorfunction

@decoratortimer(2)
def callablefunction(name):
    print(name)
print(callablefunction('John'))
```

I suggest using `time.monotonic`(which is a clock that doesnt go backwards) to increase the accuracy.

Comment: this saves me time of writing the timer again and again

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to achieve this is by purely coding the time to program. `perf_counter` offers highest accuracy from the `time` functions.

```py
from time import perf_counter, sleep
def main():
    sleep(5)

start_time = perf_counter()

main() # Function to measure

passed_time = perf_counter() - start_time

print(f"It took {passed_time}") # It took 5.007398507999824
```

Answer (score 1):

For finding your function run time prefer time.perf_counter() over time.time().
See the below link for details

[Understanding time.perf_counter() and time.process_time()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785243/understanding-time-perf-counter-and-time-process-time)

You can create your own custom timer using something like this

```
from time import perf_counter

def f(a1,a2):
    return a1 * a2

def timer(f,*args):
    start = perf_counter()
    f(*args)
    return (1000 * (perf_counter()-start)) # this returns time in ms 

a1 = np.random.rand(100)
a2 = np.random.rand(100)

np.mean([timer(f,a1,a2) for _ in range(100)]) # average out result for 100 runs
```

If you are using jupyter notebook use the following

```
%%timeit
f(a1,a2)
```

Comment: How can I use %%timeit in VSCode or in free online python tools?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code just release this feature https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_87#_command-duration-tracked

I use https://ohmyz.sh/ with the https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k theme and it give you the duration of every command you run over x seconds, where X is set in
~/.p10k.zsh
by
POWERLEVEL9K_COMMAND_EXECUTION_TIME_THRESHOLD.

I can't get the VS Code feature to work on my setup though. Maybe related to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146587