# Various clock measures

Tags: python

What is the suggested way to measure function duration in python? I have seen the following:

```
t0 = time.time()
# do something()
duration = time.time() - t0
```

and

```
t0 = time.perf_counter()
# do something()
duration = time.perf_counter() - t0
```

What are the differences, and which should be used for profiling, if either?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785243/understanding-time-perf-counter-and-time-process-time) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not your direct question, but the simplest way is to use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html) module:

```
from timeit import timeit

timeit(doSomething, number=int(1e6))
```

It will run the test multiple times and return the total running time. Set `number` to a fairly high number. I usually aim for a number that causes it to run for 30-60 seconds to make sure that it runs long enough to prevent small fluctuations from effecting the results too much.