# ImportError: cannot import name 'clock' from 'time' (unknown location)

Tags: python

i have a error in python code :
'from time import clock'
ImportError: cannot import name 'clock' from 'time' (unknown location)

this not working in python 3.8
can someone help

Comment: There is no variable named `clock` in the `time` module. What you are trying to do?

Answer (score 14):

`time.clock` is a method that has been deprecated since Python 3.3 and removed from Python 3.8 ([see the Python 3.7 `time` documentation for more information](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.clock)), because its behaviour was dependent on the platform (it behaved differently on Unix compared to Windows). As the documentation suggests, you should use `time.perf_counter()` or `time.process_time()` instead. These are subtly different, see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785243/understanding-time-perf-counter-and-time-process-time) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

This happens when you use Python 3.8 and passlib version lower than 1.7.2. Try running the command below. This might help.

```
pip install --upgrade passlib==1.7.2
```

If you don't have passlib installed, just try

```
pip install passlib==1.7.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating passlib worked for me

```py
pip install passlib==1.7.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime` module for the same result:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```