# SolverStudio (Python): ImportError: cannot import name 'clock' from 'time' (unknown location)

Tags: python, excel, solver

I'm getting an error in SolverStudio while trying to run external Python. I tried to run the model in the "Transportation-PuLP External" tab in the PuLP examples sheet. The program starts with:

```
# When running External Pythpn, we use the following to connect to SolverStudio
from SolverStudio import *
# Import PuLP modeller functions
from pulp import *
```

Still, I got this error:

```
from time import clock
ImportError: cannot import name 'clock' from 'time' (unknown location)

## CPython did not complete (Error Code 1); no solution is available.
## Done
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499013/importerror-cannot-import-name-clock-from-time-unknown-location), I tried to install Passlib through `pip install passlib==1.7.2` and to upgrade it through `pip install --upgrade passlib==1.7.2`, but the error still happens.

Could you please help me? The sheet (alongside its code) can be found in the [SolverStudio zip file](https://solverstudio.org/download-install/).

Comment: "time" module doesn't contain a function (or other entity) "clock". Why do you expect this to work?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, thanks for reaching out. Actually, this was the program's output, not my input. I have edited the post to clarify this.