# why did my time.perf_counter() in python display such a large time despite it being a simple function?

Tags: python, multithreading, time, module

This is the code:

```py
import time
import threading


def hi():
    pass


x = threading.Thread(target=hi())
print(time.perf_counter())
```

For some reason, it returned 114613.1859948 seconds.
I tried again, it still hovers around the 110,000 to 120,000 range.

I also looked up tutorials on YouTube related to threads and the time.perf_counter() function and stuff like geeksforgeeks. However I can't find the problem.

Sorry if this is a silly question, as I am still very, very new to python, but I genuinely am unable to find a solution online.

Thanks a lot

Comment: also for some reason it didn't count as new lines for some of the text, sorry for the unpleasant viewing experience

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding time.perf\_counter() and time.process\_time()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785243/understanding-time-perf-counter-and-time-process-time)

Comment: You never run `hi` in a thread. `target=hi()` calls `hi` in the main thread and passes its return value (`None`) as the target. If you were to `start` or `run` the thread you would have got an exception since `None` is not callable.

Comment: @DeepSpace, Try it for yourself. No exception is thrown. The good people at Python seem to think that if you have a `Thread` whose `target` is `None`, that means you don't want it to do anything at all when it is started. I saw somebody's explanation for why that's supposed to be a Good Thing, but just at the moment, I forget. Anyway, it explains why you see questions here where somebody wrote `t=Thread(target=foo()); t.start(); t.join()`, and then they ask about some _other_ detail of their program, and they seem completely oblivious to the fact that their code all runs in a single thread.

Answer (score -2):

time.perf_counter return the time since boot in fractional seconds.
There also is time.perf_counter_ns which does the same but for nanoseconds.

Comment: i just looked up the term fractional seconds, and it says that its "the part of the time thats not an integer". 
does that mean for 114613.1859948, it means 0.1859948 second?

Comment: In this context it means "the number of seconds as a float (not an int)". So your system has gone 114613.1859948 seconds since boot, i.e. about 31.8 hours.

Comment: (Although the language doesn't guarantee that the time is measured since boot, only that the **difference** between two calls to `perf_counter()` is a valid measure of time elapsed: *The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of two calls is valid."* https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explaination, I understand it now.

Comment: i feel like this is too much to ask but still, i would like to know how to display solely the float, without the integer

Comment: If you want just the fractional part, you could do `t = time.perf_counter()` then `print(t - int(t))`

Comment: But what if i told python to count from 0 to a billion, it will take longer than 1 second. In this case, is there ways that i can retain that number without removing the integer part that it will have?

Comment: Sure, do `t1 = time.perf_counter()` before you start counting, `t2 = time.perf_counter()` after you finish counting, then `t2 - t1` is the number of seconds taken. Does that help? Sorry if I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: Basically, don't think of `perf_counter()` as a stopwatch, think of it as a clock. To find out how long something took, you always need to take two different readings and do a subtraction.